# Matplotlib 2 stacked subplots, unable to set size of BOTH ytick labels

Tags: matplotlib, subplot

My code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, sharey=False)
axs[0].plt(stuff)
axs[1].plt(stuff)
```

I've tried:

```
plt.yticks(fontsize=15)
```

and

```
plt.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=15)
```

They both change the size of the ytick labels in the lower plot, but the upper plot remains unchanged. I haven't been able to grab the upper subplot ytick label handle.

Comment: `ax[0].tick_params`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @ImportanceOfBeingErnest!

```
axs[0].tickparams()
```

This grabbed just the handle of the upper subplot.